# Order of thread activation in a c# program on a 4 cores PC

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I am confused about the thread activation order of the following C# code. It creates 10 threads, starts them randomly, each thread simulates to execute a time-consuming work 10 times, if you check the debug output, the thread seems not to be picked up not randomly, please see below output example, notice thread #3, #5, #6 is always picked up, when #3 #5 #6 is finished, then #10 #2 #8 is always picked up, etc... (I know the design is bad, please focus on the phenomenon)

My PC has i7-7820HQ cpu which has 4 cores, and is running windows 10.

Could someone explain why these threads are not picked randomly and they seemed to be grouped somehow.

Thanks a lot!

---- Debug output ----

```
Thread #10 acquired the lock and is working for task #0 
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #0 
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
...
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
...
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #10 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
...
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
Thread #10 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
...
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Hashtable _sharedBetweenThreads = new Hashtable();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Second);
            var startOrders = new int[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < startOrders.Length; i++)
            {
                startOrders[i] = i;
            }

            //shuffle the array
            for (int i = startOrders.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                int j = random.Next(0, i);
                int temp = startOrders[i];
                startOrders[i] = startOrders[j];
                startOrders[j] = temp;
            }


            Thread[] threads = new Thread[startOrders.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < startOrders.Length; i++)
            {
                threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < startOrders.Length; i++)
            {
                threads[startOrders[i]].Start();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void ThreadProc()
        {
            // simulates there are 10 tasks needs to do.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                lock (_sharedBetweenThreads.SyncRoot)
                {
                    Debug.Print(string.Format("Thread #{0} acquired the lock and is working for task #{1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i));

                    // simulates a work.
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[The screenshot of debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK30N.jpg)

--- Additional infos ---

- The program is not a parallel program at all because there is lock shared among 10 threads.
- If the count of the loop is changed from 10 to infinite, the 3 threads are always activated and the rest 7 threads cannot get a chance of activating, and they are something like "deadlocked" forever.

Comment: Try adding a `Random rng = new Random();` to `ThreadProc()` before the loop, and then in the loop doing `Thread.Sleep(400 + rng.Next(200));` and see if you get different results. Perhaps there's some kind of lock-step thing happening.

Comment: There is no order.  The OS in fact intentionally avoids accidental ordering, a counter-measure against lock convoys.  Backgrounder [is here](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/12/14/anticonvoy-locks-in-windows-server-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/).

Comment: The most confusing thing is that there are 10 threads, only 3 threads can be activated, before the loop finishes, the thread scheduler always choose these 3 threads and the rest 7 are always waiting. should not each one thread has the same chance to be activated?

Answer (score 0):

Usings threads doesn't really mean you are using the 4 cores you have.

You have to use Parallel:

```
class Program
{
    private static object _lock = new Object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Second);

        int[] startOrders = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < startOrders.Length; i++)
        {
            startOrders[i] = i;
        }

        //shuffle the array
        for (int i = startOrders.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int j = random.Next(0, i);
            int temp = startOrders[i];
            startOrders[i] = startOrders[j];
            startOrders[j] = temp;
        }


        Thread[] threads = new Thread[startOrders.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < startOrders.Length; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(ThreadProc)
                             {
                                 Name = $"#{startOrders[i]}"

                             };
        }


        Parallel.ForEach(threads, thread => thread.Start());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ThreadProc()
    {
        // simulates there are 10 tasks needs to do.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                Debug.Print(
                    $"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.Name} acquired the lock and is working for task #{i}");

                // simulates a work.
                Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #0
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #1
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
Thread #6 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
The thread 0xfa0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
Thread #4 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
The thread 0x329c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
Thread #5 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
The thread 0x3fcc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread #8 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
The thread 0xe2c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #3 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
The thread 0x22ec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #7 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
The thread 0x2bfc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #2
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #3
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #4
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #5
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
Thread #9 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
The thread 0x1f44 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #6
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
Thread #0 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
The thread 0x1fc8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #7
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #8
Thread #1 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
The thread 0x2ab0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread #2 acquired the lock and is working for task #9
The thread 0x2944 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x322c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x146c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3dcc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3928 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I'm not sure, but if I use the Thread.Name, instead Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId seems to work as you want. It can be that the ManagedThreadId is assigned when the thread start, so it makes sense that the #12 is the last one on the execute, because it is actually the last one.

Comment: I deliberately shuffle the array that I can start thread in a random order. There are 10 threads in total, 3 threads are always activated, the rest 7 are always waiting, they cannot get chance to run. I just want to know why there is such phenomenon.

Comment: `Parallel` will start the threads in a "random" way, that is why I commented the code to shuffle the array, because it will be already shuffle the `Thread [ ]`

Did you give a try to the code I posted?

Comment: thank you for the code, I tried, it is still the same phenomenon. I pasted a screenshot of the debug output to the thread. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK30N.jpg

Comment: Interesting, that should not be the case for Parallel, I will check it myself, give me some minutes.

Comment: Okey, I think the problem is the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`
I will update my anser.

Comment: Updated, please take a look, but @Olaf is right, you cannot simulate work with Sleep, nor parallelism with the Lock

Answer (score 0):

I guess your confusion stems from the fact, that you are using the .NET thread pool - e.g. a managed pool of threads - but you expect to deal with threads on system level, which is not quite the same. The internal thread pool gives you the thread it decides to be appropriate. This has nothing to do with the question, which core is running which thread at which moment.

Comment: does it mean such scheduling method is the way how .net managed thread pool works?

Comment: No, it seems to me there is a complete misunderstanding of parallelism and threading methods. In your code there is no parallelism at all, because of your lock. Each thread waits for the other to have finished. And with Sleep you cannot simulate work.

Comment: Thank you Olaf for the answer. Yes, just like you said, the code itself is not parallelism at all because there is a lock shared among all 10 threads, and there is only one thread that can run in one time slice, the rest 9 threads wait for the same lock.

Comment: Let's say the id of the activating thread is N, and I hope the N might be 0-9 randomly, each thread should have fair percentage to be activated, not the phenomenon described above, that only 3 (I think it should be 4, exactly the same as my core number. the total number is 1(main thread) + 3 (worker threads)) thread can always be activated. If I change the loop count from 10 to infinite, and the rest 7 threads can never be activated anymore.

Comment: The internal scheduler tries to do his job in an efficient manner. Task switching comes with a price. The scheduler decides when to switch, but he has to have a fair chance. With your lock you make that nearly impossible. Throw away your lock - you don't need it - and reduce the sleep to 50. Then your output will be the way, I guess you have expected it to be.